# Error "'Proxy object' has no attribute ..." when rendering Airflow variable `prev_execution_date_success`

Tags: airflow

During the rendering of a template that uses the Airflow variable `prev_execution_date_success`, like this:

```py
rendered_and_formatted = "{{ prev_execution_date_success.strftime('%Y%m%d') }}"
```

... I get the error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'Proxy object' has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `prev_execution_date_success` variable represents the "*execution date from prior successful dag run*", **your error will happen when no *"prior successful dag run"* exists yet**, for example when it is the first run ever of your DAG.

Comment: May I point that prev_execution_date_success is deprecated. You should not use it.

Comment: Good point @Elad , is `prev_start_date_success` the variable to use instead now ?